# how to put form element inline?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How to put each "label" and "controls class " inline

```
<div class="control-group">

            <label class="control-label">Designation</label>
            <div class="controls">
               <span>Aménagement salle informatique</span>
            </div>

            <label class="control-label">Etat</label>
            <div class="controls">
               <span>en cours</span>
            </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBzhL.png)

Comment: please, read what you need: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: ok thank you **Igor Ivancha**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `form-group` class to set in inline just like

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="bs-example">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Designation</label>
      <div class="">
        Aménagement salle informatique
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-2">avancement</label>
      <div class="">
        0
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: then how exactly do you want?

Comment: You can see the resultat that I got when you Run code snippet + Full page it's look malformed

Comment: u have to add `padding-top:7px` in `control-label` class..it will work as u want..